# Get element from tab in protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

```
<div class="tab"><br>
  <div class="main-icon-container">
    <div class="flex-container">
         <!---->
      <div class="flex-item text-center" 
         ng-repeat="icon in ctrl.data.icons | filter: tab" 
           ng-class="{ 'icon-selected': ctrl.data.selectedIcon === icon.icon }" 
              ng-click="ctrl.data.selectIcon(icon.icon)">
               <div class="icon-container">
                 <span class="cursor icon icon-location_apartment_block grey-bg">::before
            </span>
         </div>
       <p> Apartment block </p>
     </div>
    <!---->
```

How can I locate the above first element from tab in Protractor ?? 
Tab has 15 elements,this one above this is first element from tab.I want to click on the element,doesn't matter which one.

```
<div class="tab-pane active" 
           ng-repeat="tab in tabset.tabs" 
              ng-class="{active: tabset.active === tab.index}" uib-tab-content-transclude="tab" style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not fully sure, if I got the question right, but it seems to me [`cssContainingText()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText) should be your preferred option.

Your protractor code should look something like this:

```
element(by.cssContainingText('div.tab p', ' Apartment block ')).click();
```

**UPDATE**

Because there is a click-blocking-element (probably only there during page loading), Protractor first needs to wait for this element to disappear.

Therefore the use of [`ExpectedConditions`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions) seems needed.

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf($('div.click-block')),5000);
element(by.cssContainingText('div.tab p', ' Apartment block ')).click();
```

Comment: I have error message:   Failed: unknown error: Element <p>...</p> is not clickable at point (56, 304). Other element would receive the click: <div class="click-block"></div>

Comment: That doesn't sound so bad. It identified the element, but there was an overlay-element of `<div class="click-block"></div>`. The element sounds like a loading-blocker... I'll update the answer, with a "wait for element to disappear".

Comment: @Lelik_ : Glad I could help! Please be so kind and mark my answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Man, you can use XPath, and talk the way you go through the HTML document, it's a bit more work, but sometimes it's the only way.

```
FindElement(By.XPath(//tagname//tagname[@atrinbuto: value]));
```

you can use this to get at the element you want